# Volume level indicator in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, widget, volume

I'm writing a simple sound player, and I'd like have a volume level indicator that would show the current signal level of played sound. I'm able to feed the widget with the number from some range or percentage or anything.

Actually as I have the information from the decoding process, I just need the widget to visualize the level. Is there such a widget in [wxPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxPython)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the PeakMeter for that. There's an example in the wxPython demo. Or you can find it in wx.lib.agw.peakmeter. Here's a page of documentation too: http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/peakmeter_module.html#peakmeter

EDIT: I think I may have mis-read this. You can use a slider for a volume control.

Comment: No, you nailed it. PeakMeter is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot.